# Function is causing huge memory leak?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, memory, function

I have the following function:

```
void CGlEngineFunctions::GetBezierOpposite( const POINTFLOAT &a,const POINTFLOAT &center, POINTFLOAT &b, float blength )
{


    POINTFLOAT v;
    v.x = a.x - center.x;
    v.y = a.y - center.y;

    float alength = GetDistance(a,center);

    if(blength == 0)
    {
        blength = alength;
    }

    float multiplier = blength / alength;

    b.x = center.x - multiplier * v.x;
    b.y = center.y - multiplier * v.y;

}
```

I have narrowed the problem down to the least 2 lines:

```
b.x = center.x - multiplier * v.x;
b.y = center.y - multiplier * v.y;
```

Every time I call this repeatedly, memory shots up until it crashes.

I use it like this:

```
glEngine.functions.GetBezierOpposite(usrpt[0].LeftHandle,
            usrpt[0].UserPoint,usrpt[0].RightHandle,0);
```

I really do not see how this could cause any problems.
To test, I changed it to this:

```
void CGlEngineFunctions::GetBezierOpposite( const POINTFLOAT &a,const POINTFLOAT &center, POINTFLOAT &b, float blength )
{


    POINTFLOAT v;
    v.x = a.x - center.x;
    v.y = a.y - center.y;

    float alength = GetDistance(a,center);

    if(blength == 0)
    {
        blength = alength;
    }

    float multiplier = blength / alength;

    b.x = 5;
    b.y = 5;

}
```

When I do this it has absolutely no issues. I do not see how doing arithmetic can cause the memory usage to shoot up.

Thanks

could it be cause if alength and blength = 0?

```
POINTFLOAT:
float x;
float y;
```

Comment: Can you define `POINTFLOAT` for us? It's guessable, but it would be nice to make sure.

Comment: I don't know anything about the specifics of your language, but if `alength` and `blength` are zero, `float multiplier = blength / alength;` will either throw some kind of Divide by Zero exception or yield infinity.

Comment: Define a huge memory leak. How much is it losing per time through the function?

Comment: Assuming POINTFLOAT is just a simple structure (pod), there is no memory leak in this code. You're leaking(if it even is a real leak) elsewhere, and it's probably depending on the outcome of this function. Look for stuff that does malloc/new , or library calls where you have to release a resource when you're done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `GetDistance` calls this method, there may be a **Stack Overflow**.

If other threads call this method, there may be a **Stack Overflow**.

Check the POINTFLOAT definition.  IMHO, it should be modified to provide subtraction operations.  You should not need to reference any of the structure's members.  But then this comment would be about C++.

You should remove the 'C' language tag, since the C language does not provide a scope resolution operator, '::'.

Comment: Actually, I think the C tag is okay here. You don't need to understand C++ here -- the problem is applicable to both C and C++.

Answer (score 0):

If `POINTFLOAT` is some complicated `class` (you have tagged your question C++) and you have overloaded the operators in the expression, how could we know?

Also you didn't tell us much why you think these expression are the culprit, neither about your compiler, platform, OS...

Easiest way to find all this out is `valgrind` (for unixen) or some similar tool. They will tell you exactly where the allocation takes place that ends up being leaked.